# Manually connect to a user's twitter account - Spring Social

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I'm running a background task and in this task I want to consult the UserConnection database and manually connect to each user's twitter account and pull some data from twitter using users operation.

The table provides the following fields

```
 USERID
 PROVIDERID
 PROVIDERUSERID
 RANK
 DISPLAYNAME
 PROFILEURL
 IMAGEURL
 ACCESSTOKEN
 SECRET
 REFRESHTOKEN
 EXPIRETIME
```

How do I use these to connect to the user's account `(PROVIDERID = "twitter")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling the connections from the database, all I had to do was create a `Twitter` from `TwitterTemplate`.

```
List<Connection> connections = connectionRepository.findAllConnections();
for (Connection conn : connections) {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate(twitterAppKey, twitterAppSecret, conn.getAccessToken(), conn.getSecret());
    //now I can run the operations
    System.out.println(twitter.userOperations().getScreenName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am following your question correctly... You can get the Users Twitter Profile by

```
   TwitterProfile profile = getUserOperations().getUserProfile(Long.valueOf(userId));
```

OR

```
TwitterProfile profile =     getUserOperations().getUserProfile(screenName);
```

Of course you would need user or twitter app authorization via TwitterTemplate. Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Paul